# Is there a way to update a Dataflow job using the gcloud command?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, gcloud

I am trying to write a script to automate the deployment of a Java Dataflow job. The script creates a template and then uses the command

```
gcloud dataflow jobs run my-job --gcs-location=gs://my_bucket/template
```

The issue is, I want to update the job if the job already exists and it's running. I can do the update if I run the job via maven, but I need to do this via gcloud so I can have a service account for deployment and another one for running the job. I tried different things (adding --parameters update to the command line), but I always get an error. Is there a way to update a Dataflow job exclusively via gcloud dataflow jobs run?

Comment: Can you please show me the example on how to update an existing dataflow job via Maven ?

Comment: It has `--update` flag. That doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Referring to the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/dataflow/jobs), which describes `gcloud beta dataflow jobs` - a group of subcommands for working with Dataflow jobs, there is no possibility to use `gcloud` for update the job.

As for now, the Apache Beam SDKs provide a way to update an ongoing streaming job on the Dataflow managed service with new pipeline code, you can find more information [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/updating-a-pipeline). Another way of updating an existing Dataflow job is by using [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.jobs/update), where you can find Java example.

Additionally, please follow [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/153109774) regarding recreating job with `gcloud`.